# Backspace not erasing when using Console.ReadKey()

Tags: c#, console-application

I have this simple code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (!System.Console.KeyAvailable)
        {
            var key = System.Console.ReadKey(false);
        }
    }
```

When the user presses <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, the cursor just moves back but does not erase the last character.

I read some people just check if the input is <kbd>Backspace</kbd> and call `Console.Write(" \b")` to erase, but I don't know if this is the best way to resolve.

If I read input using `Console.Read()` or `Console.ReadLine()`, the character is erased when <kbd>Backspace</kbd> is pressed.

Why does the <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key change its behaviour when using `ReadKey()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `ReadKey()` you are telling .NET you want the raw input and for it to not do any processing on it. You can even tell .NET to not echo the key to the screen (via the parameter to the method).

If you use `Read()` or `ReadLine()`, you are instead telling .NET you want the input as obtained by the console logic, which includes the console imposing its own behavior on the input, such as erasing characters when the backspace key is pressed.

Two different methods for obtaining input, two different outcomes.